# GX 17 - Problema con grilla con Radio Button en Android

Tags: java, android, web, genexus, bug

Genexus 17 v 17.0.149782 U3 - Smart Devices - Android
En una grilla de mas de una pagina con un campo con un radio button, debajo de todo se marcan opciones automaticamente sin que el usuario las marque . El usuario vuelve a entrar en la pantalla y a pesar de que en la base de datos los valores ingresados estan correctos, sigue trayendo varios valores incorrectos.
Les ha ocurrido?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido, revisar [ask], agrega mayor informaciòn a tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: No tenemos reportes de este estilo. Por favor enviar tu caso con detalles y ejemplo a soporte. https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/issue-tracking . Gracias.